# Unexpected ' " ' in [...]

Tags: php

In a class I get an "Unexpected ' " ' [...] on line 22", and I can for the life of me not figure out why.

The error is on line 22

```
<?php
namespace oowp\post;

global $wpdb;

class PostObjectQueryBuilder extends QueryBuilder implements IExtendable {
    use Extendable;

    // WP Tables
    private $tablePosts;             //The table of Posts.
    private $tablePostmeta;          //The Meta Content (a.k.a. Custom Fields) table.
    private $tableComments;          //The Comments table.
    private $tableCommentmeta;       //The table contains additional comment information.
    private $tableTerms;             //The terms table contains the 'description' of Categories, Link Categories, Tags.
    private $tableTermTaxonomy;      //The term_taxonomy table describes the various taxonomies (classes of terms). Categories, Link Categories, and Tags are taxonomies.
    private $tableTermRelationships; //The term relationships table contains link between the term and the object that uses that term, meaning this file point to each Category used for each Post.
    private $tableUsers;             //The table of Users.
    private $tableUsermeta;          //The usermeta table contains additional user information, such as nicknames, descriptions and permissions.
    private $tableLinks;             //The table of Links.
    private $tableOptions;           //The Options table.

    // LINE 22 BELOW
    const BASE_QUERY = "SELECT wp.ID FROM `{$this->tablePosts}` wp
        INNER JOIN `{$this->tablePostMeta}` wm ON (wm.`post_id` = wp.`ID`)
        INNER JOIN `{$this->tableTermRelationships}` wtr ON (wp.`ID` = wtr.`object_id`)
        INNER JOIN `{$this->tableTermTaxonomy}` wtt ON (wtr.`term_taxonomy_id` = wtt.`term_taxonomy_id`)
        INNER JOIN `{$this->tableTerms}` wt ON (wt.`term_id` = wtt.`term_id`)";
```

I've tried rewriting the line in question, and I'v tried to move the const declaration to the top, as well as removing the `use` statement. Neither of which worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because class constants need to have a constant value, and your definition is not constant.

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php) on class constants:

> The value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable,
>   a property, or a function call.

You could prove that your syntax is correct outside of the class by removing `const` and turning `BASE_QUERY` into `$BASE_QUERY` and remove `$this->` as some other variable, it should parse successfully.

You could define this expression as a member variable, but not during initialization. This is because member variables in PHP must also be initialized to constant expressions. The easiest solution is to define `$BASE_QUERY` in the class, then initialize it in a constructor.

Comment: As well, I'm initializing it with instance variables, which makes no sense for a static variable(or constant). I Guess I wasn't thinking straight.

Comment: @sigsve - The error message inherently leads you away from the root cause. At least in PHP 7 the error message is spot on: `Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations `

Answer (score -1):

I DO NOT get it why you are creating a constant to have your base query.

> expression is not allowed as class constant value

It is simple to have a function with return the base query and you can call it where ever you want to use it.

```
public function getBaseQuery()
{
    return "SELECT wp.ID FROM `{$this->tablePosts}` wp
    INNER JOIN `{$this->tablePostMeta}` wm ON (wm.`post_id` = wp.`ID`)
    INNER JOIN `{$this->tableTermRelationships}` wtr ON (wp.`ID` = wtr.`object_id`)
    INNER JOIN `{$this->tableTermTaxonomy}` wtt ON (wtr.`term_taxonomy_id` = wtt.`term_taxonomy_id`)
    INNER JOIN `{$this->tableTerms}` wt ON (wt.`term_id` = wtt.`term_id`)";
}
```